# Cannot connect to hotspot after restart (not IP address error on Phone)

Tags: raspbian, networking

Hardware:

Pi-4
OS -raspbian

I followed the following guide :https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

Now it works great , I could Connect to the hot spot until I restarted the PI then Im receiving error on my phone "Couldnt get IP Address"

If I try wrong Password I do get wrong password error.

Files:

```
 dnsmasq.conf:

interface=wlan0 # Listening interface

dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h

                # Pool of IP addresses served via DHCP

domain=wlan     # Local wireless DNS domain

address=/gw.wlan/192.168.4.1

 # Alias for this router


hostapd
    interface=wlan0
    ssid=NameOfNetwork
    hw_mode=g
    channel=7
    macaddr_acl=0
    auth_algs=1
    ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
    wpa=2
    wpa_passphrase=AardvarkBadgerHedgehog
    wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    wpa_pairwise=TKIP
    rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 is enabled

Comment: If you like you can also try [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Apparently You need to set the IP of the PI after restarting the hotspot after connection to WIFI ,
Just run ifconfig wlan0  for me it was ifconfig wlan0 192.168.X.X
And everything will work

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.